# Load data frame with spanish characters into RStudio on Windows 10

Tags: r, utf-8

I have the following data frame (saved as .RData):

```
Matemáticas <- c(sample(70:100, 10, replace=TRUE))
Química <- c(sample(70:100, 10, replace=TRUE))
notas <- data.frame(Matemáticas,Química)
```

When loading it to the Global Environment on my Mac, I have no problems. However, when I try to do so in Windows 10 on a PC (RStudio version 3.3.3), the variable names appear as such:

```
QuÃmica
MatemÃ¡ticas
```

I have tried the following things:
1. I have already set the default text encoding to UTF-8 in Tools->Global Options -> Code -> Saving -> Default text encoding.
2. I tried changing the locale, with the following:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL",Spanish)
Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE",Spanish)
```

This changed the locale, when I checked with 
    Sys.getlocale()
but the accents still appeared.

3. I tried changing the encoding of the data frame itself with 
   Encoding(notas) <- "UTF-8"
   This did not work because (I suspect) I have to do a sapply or something...

Most of the information I have found online is in reference to reading spanish characters when reading a csv file, but my file is in .RData already.

What I would like is for Windows to ALWAYS recognize spanish accents, as most of my work is in this language.

Comment: Can you try to save your df in a csv (on Windows) and then load it (on Mac)?

Comment: I could, but would prefer a solution with the .RData file...I need it to work on both computers as .RData because its part of a knitr file, so when compiling it I don't wan't an extra step.

Comment: I some cases (esp. OSX <10.10) Rstudio can show characters with wrong encoding, but it sometimes is merely a frontend issue. Can you check if your data is saved properly? (i.e. if it affects the underlying data)

Comment: But the characters appear ok on my mac, and everything runs smoothly. The problem is only on WIndows on a PC